# Why was Angular 3 skipped, and what are the major differences in Angular 4 beta

Tags: angular

I just noticed that the Angular 4 beta was released, but cannot find much info on it. I'm making an app in Angular 2 right now and am kind of scared that Angular 4 is what I should be using.

What are the differences? Why did the team skip Angular 3, or have I just been living under a rock?

Comment: Well I am more so just curious

Comment: They're skipping 3 because the router is already on that version and they want the numbers to align again.

Comment: It just a change to semantic versioning. No big breaking changes should appear and 4.0 will be backwards compatible with 2.3.* They made this change because the current angular 2 version is 2.3.1 and the router is 3.3.1 I think because they release a few version of router.

Comment: Here you go! => https://toddmotto.com/please-stop-worrying-about-angular-3

Comment: Messy, try to use Vuejs instead in your next project :)

Answer (score 43):

- Angular is being developed in a **MonoRepo** it means a single repo for everything. `@angular/core`, `@angular/compiler`, `@angular/router` etc are in the same repo and may have their own versions.
- The advantage of MonoRepo is, you don’t have to deal with the versioning of the code dependencies.
  [image]

- Now the problem is with the @angular/router which is already in a 3.X version. And that’s because of some active and huge developments on the router section, like route-preload.
- Now releasing Angular as version 3, with its router on version 4 will create confusion
- To avoid this confusion they decided to skip the version 3 and release with version 4.0.0, so that every major dependency in the MonoRepo are on the right track.

Answer (score 10):

Because they wanted to sync the angular version with the angular router version.
Angular will have a new version release every six months but Angular 4 will be backwards compatible with Angular 2/
https://www.gurustop.net/newsletter/19

Comment: The move to Angular 4 also comes with a change to semver; Angular 4 will not be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 8):

> [Due to this misalignment of the router package’s version, the team decided to go straight for Angular v4.](http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html#Why_not_version_3_then_62)