# Converting routing of Angular[2] V3, Dart 1 to Angular 5, Dart 2

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I'm busy migrating from Dart1 to Dart2 and as a result, i had to upgrade Angular from 3 to 5 as well.

I got stuck on the routing migration ...

This is what we had in Angular2 which was the same in Angular3:

```
@Component(
    ...
)
@RouteConfig(const [

    /*Meta*/
    const Route(path: "/home", component: AppHomeScene,
        name: SceneRoute.APP_HOME_SCENE, useAsDefault: true),
    const Route(path: "/project-home", component: ProjectHomeScene,
        name: SceneRoute.PROJECT_HOME_SCENE,),
    ...

])
class AppBuild implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
    ...
}
```

In Angular5, i've removed that `@RouteConfig` block, created a `routes.dart` and a `paths.dart`

```
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';
import 'package:appbuild/enum/enums.dart';

class Paths {

    static final home = new RoutePath(path: "home", useAsDefault: true, additionalData: SceneRoute.APP_HOME_SCENE);

    ...
}
```

and

```
import 'package:appbuild/paths.dart';

export 'paths.dart';

class Routes {

    static final all = <RouteDefinition>[

        /*Meta*/
        RouteDefinition(routePath: Paths.home, component: AppHomeScene),

        ...
    ];
}
```

Where i currently have `component: AppHomeScene`, the docs says it should be in the format `hero_list_template.HeroListComponentNgFactory,`

[image]

If i try to do the import though, IntelliJ marks it as an error:

```
import 'component/home/home-scene.template.dart' as 'home-scene-template';
```

[image]

At what point is that template generated for me to be able to do such an import or should i be doing something to the `HomeScene` class in order for that template to be importable?

`HomeScene` is just a standard component still in its Angular3 format:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'home-scene',
    // language=CSS
    styles: const[""" 
        ...
    """
    ],
    // language=HTML
    template: """
        ...
    """,
    providers: const [...],
    directives: const [...]
)
class AppHomeScene extends AppScene implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {

    ....

}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Angular 3 doesn't exist.

Comment: Angular3 = Angular2 V3: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular2/versions/3.1.0+1

Comment: Oh ok, you mean the Angular version along with Dart! A bit ambigous at first read ^^

Comment: Angular2 got rebranded to just Angular and then V3, V4, V5 was released with V6 being in beta i believe. AngularDart and AngularTypeScript also doing their own things it seems just to make it a bit more confusing :-D

Comment: Haha you're right about confusing version number ^^ However, Angular 3 never existed. It has been AngularJS > Angular 2, 4, 5, 6, and 7 has been released some days ago. See this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164866/why-was-angular-3-skipped-and-what-are-the-major-differences-in-angular-4-beta

Anyway, it doesn't solve your issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template.dart file is created for each .dart file that has a template after the first build is run on your application. IntelliJ doesn't know to compile your application before it should analyze your code.

Suggest you do a build of your app, and then refresh the analysis results.